# Awk command inside pipe inside find

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, find

I would like to run the following code:

```
find 2017_01_04/* -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c\
'file -i $1\ |  awk "{/video|audio/} {print \$1}" ' _ {} \; -print0 | \
while read -d $'\0' -r i
    echo $i
done
```

The output of `file -i` command it is:

```
20170115_202630:                      image/jpeg; charset=binary
20170115_202630.jpg:                  image/jpeg; charset=binary
20171006_204647000_iOS.MOV:           video/quicktime; charset=binary
Ei*foto.jpg:                          image/jpeg; charset=binary
err-organiza_fotos (cópia).log:       text/plain; charset=utf-8
err-organiza_fotos.log:               text/plain; charset=utf-8
err-organiza_fotos (outra cópia).log: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

The command above works fine! But when inside the `find ... -exec sh -c '... | awk ...' _ {} \; -print0 | while ...; do ...; done` doesn't work. Tried everything I know, no success.

```
file -i * | awk -F ":" '/image|video/ {print $1}'
```

My goal is to be able to find files and select only ones of a certain type, without have to check for extensions, because, for example there are image files without extensions. And I must use find, because it deals better with files with different names like `./ASD '[]ª\.*`. And finally I would like everything in just one command, I know it could be possible using the power of awk and find.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483871/how-to-find-files-by-file-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `find` command like that is much simpler as a `for` loop:

```
for f in 2017_01_04/*; do
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue
  file -i "$f" | awk '/video|audio/ {print $1}'
done
```

I assume the extra braces from your `awk` command were a typo, and the `while` loop following `find` didn't seem to serve any immediate purpose. Whatever the body really was (instead of `echo "$i"`) could just as easily be the next member of the pipeline in the body of my `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right, for is much more simple. I'm going to simplify my code. Find is not good for dealing with filenames, I believed the opposite. The extra braces in my awk weren't typo, I guess, they were necessary because the single comma  required for the sh -c command. The while after find were absolutely necessary to create a loop. Using find results, even when you put into a variable, they are not divided into lines and then you can't use in a for loop. But you solution is better, simpler, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So break it down to something simpler and build on that eg:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec file -i {} \; | grep 'video\|image'
```

which gives (in one of my own directories):

```
./20190102_104158.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
./20190102_104158-1.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
./20190102_104951-1.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
./20190102_104212.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
./20190102_104158-2.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
./kitchen_sink_set.dwg: image/vnd.dwg; charset=binary
./20190102_104951.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
./20190102_104212-1.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
./20190102_104852.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
./20190102_111832-1.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
```

Comment: This works better. I was trying to do everything in the same command but I realized that it is not good, to many exceptions to deal. For example, in my command, the while creates a subshell. I will split my code. Thanks.